# Fixing hover to navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I created a WordPress theme of my own and I have a problem:

I have a navigation with `border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px / 8px 8px 8px 8px`; and every time I hover my navigation and I really want to put `border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px / 8px 8px 8px 8px;` but I don't see any result.

I already tried different things but it seems I can't determine how to fix this one.

Here is my [**Fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/TJe8w/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78GKL/)

```
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px / 8px 8px 8px 8px !important;
}
```

Add this code and you will get your desired result.

Comment: is it possible to do it only with the class "active" ?

Comment: No. As you want the border-radius to be `8px 8px 8px 8px / 8px 8px 8px 8px` when `hovering`, you would have to add the class `hover`. However you can also add the `active` class along with `hover`. Simply, add `#cssmenu ul li:hover` with `#cssmenu ul li:hover` in the above code. You will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
#cssmenu ul li:hover,
#cssmenu ul li.active {
  background: #2d78b2;

  /* Old browsers */


}
```

with this:

```
   #cssmenu ul li:hover:nth-child(1),
#cssmenu ul li.active {
background: #2d78b2;
border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px !important;
  /* Old browsers */


}

#cssmenu ul li:hover,
#cssmenu ul li.active {
  background: #2d78b2;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* Old browsers */


}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TJe8w/2/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing border-radius on `li`. Here is the css you need to update.

```
#cssmenu ul li{border-radius: 8px;}
```

And you can check it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RMLgC/2/)